# How to configure Serilog sink wrapper and wrapped sinks

Tags: serilog

Following [C. Augusto Proiete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211672/c-augusto-proiete)'s answer to [How to change the LogLevel of specific log events in Serilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68832054/how-to-change-the-loglevel-of-specific-log-events-in-serilog_), the code below works, but what is the recommended way to move this configuration to a configuration file. Keeping [Serilog.Settings.Xml](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-settings-xml) would be our preference, but we'd consider other options.

Also, is there a problem writing to two sinks? Or has that been resolved?

```c#
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Xml(serilogXmlFilePath)
    .WriteTo.LogLevelModifierSink(writeTo => {
        writeTo.File(
            outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}{ThreadId}",
            path: @"C:\inetpub\logs\serilog.txt",
            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
            shared: true);
        writeTo.Seq("http://localhost/seq/");
    })
    .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serilog configuration extensions such as [`Serilog.Settings.Xml`](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-settings-xml), [`Serilog.Settings.Configuration`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/), etc. all work the same way: They **try to find an extension method that matches the sink name and arguments in your configuration**.

i.e. When you do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<serilog>
  <using>
    <add name="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
  </using>
  
  <writeTo>
    <sink name="File">
      <arg name="path" value="log.txt" />
    </sink>
  </writeTo>
</serilog>
```

The Serilog configuration extension tries to run a method that looks like this:

```
public static LoggerConfiguration File(
    this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerSinkConfiguration, string path)
{
   // ...
}
```

Which in this example, is the method provided by the [Serilog.Sinks.File](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/blob/v5.0.0/src/Serilog.Sinks.File/FileLoggerConfigurationExtensions.cs#L251-L253).

In your case, given that you're creating a custom sink, you'd also have to provide a custom extension method that can receive all the parameters needed to configure the sink(s), and then you set up accordingly. So it would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<serilog>

  <using>
    <add name="Namespace.Where.Your.Extension.Method.Is" />
  </using>

  <writeTo>
    <sink name="LogLevelModifier">
      <arg name="filePath" value="C:\inetpub\logs\serilog.txt" />
      <arg name="seqUrl" value="http://localhost/seq/" />
    </sink>
  </writeTo>

</serilog>
```

---

```
// Extension method to hook the wrapper into the configuration extension
public static class LoggerSinkConfigurationLogLevelModifierExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration LogLevelModifier(
        this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerSinkConfiguration,
        string filePath = null,
        string seqUrl = null)
    {
        return LoggerSinkConfiguration.Wrap(loggerSinkConfiguration, sink =>
            new LogLevelModifierSink(sink), writeTo =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
                {
                    writeTo.File(filePath);
                }
                
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(seqUrl))
                {
                    writeTo.Seq(seqUrl);
                }

                // etc.

            }, LevelAlias.Minimum, null);
    }
}
```