# How to log 'meta' events, such as a minimum level change?

Tags: serilog

I would like to log meta information about the logging itself, such as the change of the minimum LogEventLevel. I could tag it with some "meta" property and give it level "Fatal". This works, because sinks and subloggers can filter based on the property, and the fatal level ensures it is always propagated to every sink, such that a sink can choose to log meta events regardless of the current minumum LogEventLevel.

However, the obvious problem is that this makes these log events show as "Fatal", which is misleading at least and ugly at best.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a sink wrapper that checks for the presence of your `meta` property and modifies the log level from `Fatal` to the most appropriate level that would satisfy the minimum level of the target sinks, before the change is made. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68854607/211672

Comment: The answer you point to does not contain an Enricher. How would you do it using an enricher?

Comment: Ops, it was a typo. I meant sink wrapper, not enricher. The answer I linked is the correct one. Enrichers can't modify the `LogEventLevel` so you need a sink wrapper for that

Answer (score 0):

Have two separate sublogger channels to the same inner logger, one for the meta events and one for the application events.

```
    internal static ILogger _applicationLogger;
    internal static ILogger _metaLogger;
    internal static ILogger _innerLogger;
```

The application logger can then have the level switch, while the meta logger remains untouched.

```
        _innerLogger = myconfig.CreateLogger();
        _metaLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Logger(_innerLogger)
            .CreateLogger();
        _applicationLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(LogLevelSwitch)
            .WriteTo.Logger(_innerLogger)
            .CreateLogger();
```